# Laravel SystemPay after the payment URL Post

Tags: laravel

I use https://paiement.systempay.fr for the credit card payments in my application

In the SystemPay rules i have to define an URL to callback when the transaction is finish the method is POST , systempay send me back all the information on the transaction and i need to get all the parameters in a $_POST VARIABLE

My question is : I would like to create a route like : mydomaine.com/checkout/verification.php and check with a var dump if i got the POST INFO from systemPay serveur.

How could i do this in the routes with a .php and check the result ?

Hope someone could help me

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do this.  That route would be requested from systempay's system so they would get that response if you var_dumped that data.  You'd want to `\Log::info('SystemPay', ['postData' => $_POST]);` which would put everything into your `laravel.log` file.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! In need to put \Log::info... in my php page ?